# i have given a soap service in xml how can i execute it

Tags: soap

I have this SOAP service in xml format i need to execute it how do i do this in java and also i need to know is it necessary to know all the credentials that has been given in this soap to access the file as i am very new to SOAP api i need some guidance from you

```
     <ServiceRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
      xmlns:m="urn:messages.service.ti.apps.tiplus2.misys.com" 
      xmlns:c="urn:common.service.ti.apps.tiplus2.misys.com"         
      xmlns="urn:control.services.tiplus2.misys.com">
     <RequestHeader>
     <Service>TI</Service>
     <Operation>InvoiceCustomer</Operation>
     <Credentials>
     <Name>Name</Name>
     <Password>Password</Password>
     <Certificate>Certificate</Certificate>
     <Digest>Digest</Digest>
     </Credentials>
     <ReplyFormat>FULL</ReplyFormat>
     <NoRepair>Y</NoRepair>
     <NoOverride>Y</NoOverride>
     <CorrelationId>CorrelationId</CorrelationId>
     <TransactionControl>NONE</TransactionControl>
     </RequestHeader>
     <m:InvoiceCustomer>
     <m:MaintType>MaintType</m:MaintType>
 <m:MaintainedInBackOffice>MaintainedInBackOffice</m:MaintainedInBackOffice>
 <m:Customer>
    <c:SourceBankingBusiness>SourceBankingBusiness</c:SourceBankingBusiness>
    <c:Mnemonic>Mnemonic</c:Mnemonic>
    </m:Customer>
    <m:InvoiceFor>InvoiceFor</m:InvoiceFor>
    <m:AvailableLimit>
    <c:Amount>Amount</c:Amount>
    <c:Currency>Currency</c:Currency>
    </m:AvailableLimit>
    </m:InvoiceCustomer>
    </ServiceRequest>
```